# SQL JOIN single value without TOP function

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by, left-join

Plenty of examples to be found on SQL joins based on min/max values, however my db does NOT support `TOP` function and many solutions seem to be geared towards using that. I have some trouble getting my head around it, hence trying with a simple query.

```
select 
    a.custID, b.lineNO, b.comment 
from 
    CUSTOMER a
left join 
    COMMENT b on a.custID = b.comcustID
```

I have a one-to-many relationship here with single `a.custID`, however multiple `b.comment`. How can I `JOIN` only single `b.comment` value that has `max` `(b.lineNO)`

No problems doing this via `MAX` aggregate function based on this example, however a need to run (min/max) `JOIN` tends to come up every now and then and I'd like to understand how to write a query like that. Which is better for performance, joining single min/max value or running aggregate function such as `MAX`?

Unfortunately not sure on the actual db engine, however have found `TOP` as the first function not to run from basic things. Good chance it's something from IBM. Thanks!

Comment: Please find out what's database engine you are using. Voting to close, otherwise.

Comment: Does DB2 or Netezza ring a bell?

Answer (score 1):

Pleae check the answer below:

```
select a.custID, b.lineNO, b.comment from CUSTOMER a
left join comment b
  on  a.custID = b.comcustID and 
      b.bLineNo = (select max(bLineNo) from customer cin where cin.comcustID = b.comcustID)
```

Comment: Worked out along with the one from Nigel. Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a one-to-many relationship here with single a.custID, however multiple b.comment. How can I JOIN only single b.comment value that has max (b.lineNO)

I suspect that you want :

```
SELECT
    a.custID,
    c.lineNO,
    c.comment 
FROM 
    CUSTOMER a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT comcustID, MAX(lineNO) as max_line_no
        FROM COMMENTS
        GROUP BY comcustID
    ) b ON b.comcustID = a.custID
    INNER JOIN COMMENTS c 
        ON c.comcustID = b.comcustID
        AND c.lineNO = b.max_line_no
```

NB : you did not tag the RDBMS that you are using. The above query uses common SQL idiom, that are supported by most RDBMS (mysql, sqlite, oracle, mssql, postgres, ...)

Answer (score 0):

As people have commented, you really need to find out what DB you're using. But for a quick solution now...

```
SELECT a.custID, b.lineNO, b.comment FROM CUSTOMER a
LEFT JOIN COMMENT b on a.custID = b.comcustID
 AND b.lineNO = (SELECT MAX(b.lineNO) FROM COMMENT b WHERE a.custID = b.comcustID)
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Also felt like the easiest one to implement

Answer (score 0):

Another method uses window functions:

```
select cu.custID, co.lineNO, co.comment
from CUSTOMER cu left join
     (select co.*,
             row_number() over (partition by co.comcustID order by co.lineNO desc) as seqnum
      from COMMENT co
     ) co
     on cu.custID = co.comcustID and co.seqnum = 1;
```